wkwebview load website and replace files with local version
In WkWebView, I would like to open a website from an URL, replacing certain files form locally stored files.
I'm beginner, and only was able to came to this point:
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: configuration)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/")!))

In Android I got it working like this:
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
        view: WebView,
        request: WebResourceRequest
    ): WebResourceResponse? {
        if (request.url.path == "/example.html") {
            val stream: InputStream = assets.open("example.html")
            return WebResourceResponse("text/html", "UTF-8", stream)
        }
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
    }
}

How can I achieve the same thing in iOS Swift ?
